# why <span> element is showing bottom padding & bottom border and top border & top padding is messed up?

Tags: html, css, border, padding, margin

i know that span element is an inline element, with display : inline ; property by default . if i apply any top or bottom margin, border or padding to it that won't work (unless applying display : inline-block or block).

but in my example , why the border-top & padding-top are vanished or messed up with the viewport? and padding-bottom & border-bottom are showing ?

```css
span {
    margin: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <span>google</span>
 </body>
```

another thing happened : if i put couple of br in the top of my span then the border-top & padding-top are visible?

```css
span {
    margin: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <span>google</span>
 </body>
```

why this is happening? please someone explain (i am using google chrome to view the results) -thanks

Comment: *if i apply any top or bottom margin, border or padding to it that won't work* --> this is not correct. It works but it will not affect the layout thus you will have overflow like in your first example

Comment: That is because of the `padding:20px;` in stretches inside.